Embedded Unity Game not building, Error message: Brotli compression may not be supported over HTTP connections
So just to test things out for a future project, I created a Unity game which I want to host on my Next.js website. I downloaded with WebGL from Unity and I placed the game files inside the Public folder in my website. I then embedded the game into my website with iframe.
However, this error message is popping up Error message
Here is my website structure: Website Structure
So far I have

Inserted the game files into my project.

Created a component using iframe to try and display that game.


I am not sure where the issue is or if I need to configure anything further. Any help at all would be appreciated!
Thanks.

That isn't a build problem, it's a web server configuration issue. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-deploying.html


Install https on your local server to test your site on.
Check that all your game assets are being loaded into the game from https.

